# primeng checkbox ngmodel is not known property

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using p-checkbox pf prime ng 4.1 rc2 version

I am getting the below error

```
Can't bind to 'ngModel' since it isn't a known property of 'p-checkbox'.
```

i have added the common module,form module  in app.module.ts but still it is not working

Comment: Please include the code.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> *ngModel* is part of *FormsModule*, that is why you will need to import FormsModule from @angular/forms and add it inside imports metadata option of *NgModule*. After doing this, you should be able to use *ngModel* directive in the templates that belong to the module where *FormsModule* was imported.

**mymodule.module.ts**

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule }    from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule, FormsModule,...
```